# Combine whereRaw() with leftjoin() using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to join 2 tables and get the latest unique results using `whereRaw()` and `leftJoin()` with Laravel eloquent.

I have 2 tables:-

skills table (has timestamps):-

```
| id|   name  |  icon      |
| 1 | skill 1 | skill1.png |
| 2 | skill 2 | skill2.png |
| 3 | skill 3 | skill3.png |
```

scores table (has timestamps):-

```
| id| player_id | skill_id | score |
| 1 | 1         | 1        | 1     |
| 2 | 1         | 2        | 1     |
| 3 | 1         | 3        | 1     |
| 4 | 1         | 2        | 2     |
```

I would like to return all skills but only the latest entry(by id), so for the above snippet I should get:-

```
| id| player_id | name    | skill_id | score |
| 1 | 1         | skill 1 | 1        | 1     |
| 3 | 1         | skill 3 | 1        | 1     |
| 4 | 1         | skill 2 | 2        | 2     |
```

I can get the latest unique records by using:

```
return SkillScores::where('player_id', $this->id)
        ->whereRaw('id in (select max(id) from skills group by (name))')
        ->get();
```

I can get the skill names by using:-

```
return SkillScores::where('player_id', $this->id)
        ->leftJoin('skills', 'skill_scores.skill_id', '=', 'skills.id')
        ->get();
```

but when I combine them I get an SQLSTATE[23000] error

```
return SkillScores::where('player_id', $this->id)
        ->whereRaw('id in (select max(id) from skills group by (name))')
        ->leftJoin('skills', 'skill_scores.skill_id', '=', 'skills.id')
        ->get();
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going wrong?

EDIT:-

It turns out that the SQLSTATE[23000] error is occuring because I have an id column in both tables and I havent told it which one I am referencing, the below fixes the issue and gives me the correct result.

```
return SkillScores::where('player_id', $this->id)
        ->whereRaw('skill_scores.id in (select max(skill_scores.id) from skill_scores group by (skill_id))')
        ->leftJoin('skills', 'skill_scores.skill_id', '=', 'skills.id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is a minor problem on your expected result(id and name is not matching) but i made it work as following;

The query;

```sql
SELECT scores.*, skills.*
FROM scores
         INNER JOIN (SELECT skill_id, max(id) AS maxId
                     FROM scores
                     WHERE player_id = 1
                     GROUP BY skill_id) AS sub ON sub.maxId = scores.id
         INNER JOIN skills ON skills.id = scores.skill_id;
```

The eloquent version (You may replace it with `DB::table()` if you want)

```
$subQuery = Score::where('player_id', DB::raw($this->id))
   ->groupBy('skill_id')
   ->select('skill_id', DB::raw('MAX(id) as maxId'));

return Score::join(DB::raw('(' . $subQuery->toSql() . ') as subQuery'), 'subQuery.maxId', '=', 'scores.id')
    ->join('skills', 'skills.id', '=', 'scores.skill_id')
    ->get(['scores.*', 'skills.*']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are correct I had a minor problem with the expected results, just a copy and paste issue which I have now corrected. Your solution does work but I have now managed to correct the mistake in the code I used, please see my edit above,

Comment: @Chris `SELECT max(scores.id) FROM scores GROUP BY (skill_id)` by using this you are not filtering anything which means that you are grouping skill_id for all the users not just user_id =1

Comment: @Chris rest is same logic, you are just left joining and using wherein i used inner join. If my answer is working that's good, there may be several ways to do it, i showed one of them. I am not sure what do you mean. "thanks for the answer it is working - but i found another way". okay that's good.

Comment: I didn't realise that I was grouping the skill_id for all the users, I thought that the first where('player_id', $this->id) would catch that but now that I have added extra users into the table I can see what you mean and your solution does indeed cover this.